# Change webserver user upon login

Tags: php, apache

I am having trouble in accessing files on the server.
`exec(whoami)` returns `apache`. However, files that I have to read and write through PHP scripts have a username as `ben` like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ben staff 1000 Mar 27 17:54 backup_1.sql
-rw-r----- 1 ben staff 2000 Mar 27 17:54 backup_2.sql
```

Setting write permission to apache on this subdirectory will do the job, but then I am concerned of security.

On my website, I have a login system. Is there a way to change a webserver user to `ben` upon logging-in to a specific account in database, say `admin`?
Is it even possible to change the webserver username from `apache` to something else?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to change the webserver username from apache to
>   something else?

You need to change the User and Group directive in Apache configuration file. In Ubuntu the main configuration file is `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
User ben 
Group staff
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: What about if I dont have access to httpd.config?  Is it possible to change it through php?

Comment: No, you can't through php. At that point your user and group are already set.

Comment: Oh I see. Then will the change in httpd.config allow everyone to have permission to read/write files? Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I think, your best option is changing file ownership to www-data or apache (depends on your distro)